# deadbolt pins fell out when i try to take my broken key out

Tags: repair

my key broke off in the deadbolt and I had to take it apart to get the key out but the pens in the springs fell out the lock how do I put them back in which order Do they go in

Comment: Not easy. You need to insert the pins so that the valleys on the key cause the different lengths of pins to align with a critical point in the turning mechanism.  It is often impossible to see the alignment and you are stuck with trial and error. For most locks, a new cylinder is relatively cheap, although it means distributing new keys to all users.

Answer (score 1):

This little picture shows how you have to get the pins installed so that the key will allow the lock cylinder to rotate properly.

[image]